# Сборка библиотеки SoLoud на Ubuntu

Tags: linux, c

Нашел библиотеку для работы со звуками [SoLoud](http://sol.gfxile.net/soloud/c_api.html), скачал, почитал документацию, скопировал из нее пример:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "soloud_c.h"
int main(int parc, char ** pars)
{
    Soloud *soloud = Soloud_create();
    Speech *speech = Speech_create();

    Speech_setText(speech, "Hello c-api");

    Soloud_initEx(soloud, SOLOUD_CLIP_ROUNDOFF | SOLOUD_ENABLE_VISUALIZATION, SOLOUD_AUTO, SOLOUD_AUTO, SOLOUD_AUTO, 2);

    Soloud_setGlobalVolume(soloud, 4);
    Soloud_play(soloud, speech);



    Soloud_deinit(soloud);
    
    Speech_destroy(speech);
    Soloud_destroy(soloud);

    return 0;
}
```

Скомпилировал:

```
gcc -I soloud20200207/include/ main.c -o main
```

Но компилятор выдает неопределенные ссылки на все функции в коде, в документации написано что нужно подключать либо dll либы, либо статические либы, но где взять эти статические либы я не понимаю. Как мне собирать SoLoud, учитывая что я работаю на Ubuntu, а не на винде?

язык Си.

Comment: @0xdb, так в этом вопросе выясняют причины, у меня же есть причина - не могу найти статические библиотеки для сишки

Comment: надо [собрать](https://github.com/jarikomppa/soloud/blob/master/build/readme.txt) сам soloud из его исходников. Для этого надо сгенерировать файлы системы сборки с помощью [GENie](https://github.com/bkaradzic/genie). Тебе скорей всего нужен будет make или ninja. ЗЫ: ни библиотека ни система сборки не особо популярны, так что с деталями этого процесса ты скорей всего один на один...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, замечательно